# Split an array in rows and columns

Tags: python, list, numpy

Using Python 2.

I need to split an array into their rows and columns but I don't seem to get the solution as asked in the exercise

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[5, 0, 3, 3],
 [7, 9, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 7, 6],
 [8, 8, 1, 6]])
```

So far I have these functions

```
def _rows(a):
    print("array:"+ str(a[:,]))
_rows(a)
def _col(a):
    alt=a.T
    print ("array:"+ str(alt[:,]))
_col(a)
```

but I need to return a list and when I use the `list()` function it separe each individual character

I need the result to be:

```
[array([5, 0, 3, 3]), array([7, 9, 3, 5]), array([2, 4, 7, 6]), array([8, 8, 1, 6])]

[array([5, 7, 2, 8]), array([0, 9, 4, 8]), array([3, 3, 7, 1]), array([3, 5, 6, 6])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems you're on Python 2:

```
>>> l1, l2 = list(a), list(a.T)
>>> l1
[array([5, 0, 3, 3]), array([7, 9, 3, 5]), array([2, 4, 7, 6]), array([8, 8, 1, 6])]
>>> l2
[array([5, 7, 2, 8]), array([0, 9, 4, 8]), array([3, 3, 7, 1]), array([3, 5, 6, 6])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can unpack the rows and columns into a list with:

```
res1, res2 = [*a], [*a.T]
```

---

```
print(res1)

[array([5, 0, 3, 3]),
 array([7, 9, 3, 5]),
 array([2, 4, 7, 6]),
 array([8, 8, 1, 6])]

print(res2)

[array([5, 7, 2, 8]),
 array([0, 9, 4, 8]),
 array([3, 3, 7, 1]),
 array([3, 5, 6, 6])]
```

---

[Extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) was introduced in python 3.0, for older versions you can call the list constructor as in @U9-Forward 's answer

Comment: thanks, do I have to import something to be able to use the ```*``` because it gives me a syntax error

Comment: I'm guessing you have python 2. This was [introduced in python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). Let me add some alternative for older versions @GonzalodeQuesada

Comment: thanks, I also have python 3 but I'm trying to solve an error regarding the numpy import, so, for now, I'm using python 2

Comment: Just `list(a)` works. `[*a]` doesn't work for python 3.4.4 (nor for python 2). In older python3 the error is `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`.

Comment: `doesn't work for python 3.4.4` sure it does. It was [introduced in python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) @nicola

Comment: @yatu I tried on my installation and it doesn't work with the error I quoted. Did you care to check by yourself or just relied on the doc? It might be a bug or something peculiar to my installation, but I receive an error.